# Microsoft Teams deep link to tab with iframe

Tags: deep-linking, microsoft-teams

I tried to deep link a Microsoft Teams static Tab containing an iframe.

The link to the tab works but I want to change the iframe based on the deep link. Which is possible with the use of task modules, since task modules use `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/<APP_ID>**?url=<TaskInfo.url>**&height=<TaskInfo.height>&width=<TaskInfo.width>&title=<TaskInfo.title>`
Which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/learn/modules/msteams-task-modules/5-exercise-use-adaptive-cards-deep-links).

while deep links to tabs use
`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityId>?webUrl=<entityWebUrl>&label=<entityLabel>&context=<context>`

I know about the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab) for deep links in teams.

But I can't manage to achieve the same with the iframe as with the task module. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but basically you need some code your side to intercept what's coming in from Teams, and directing/setting the iframe src appropriately. For instance, on the deeplink, you can set the "subEntityId", which you could use to indicate which page you want to show in your frame. You'd need to query the Teams js `context` in your "container" page, in that case, and set the src of the iframe to the respective destination. You would be accessing `context.subEntityId`. It's possible to do this using the querystring options as well, I think. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context#getting-context-by-inserting-url-placeholder-values) for more.